# Search Server: Configuring result source with automatically appended wildcard stopped working

Tags: 2016, search-results

We configured a custom result source to automatically append the wildcard (*) character to the given search term (SP2016 On Premises). It worked alright for several months but all of a sudden stopped working. As the same happened on one of our development servers this may be due to a system update.

The funny thing is that it only affects on the list/library search box, the global search box keeps appending the wildcard character from using the same result source.

Configuration:

```
{searchTerms}*
```

**Edit**

The current version is: 16.0.4873.1000.

The query executed by the in-place in the document library view search has the following format:

```
.../_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List=%7B83F0B482-2581-4D4E-BAFF-41BD8A76E6BF%7D&View=%7B41FE36C3-B74E-4881-8CEB-AAEF2A426960%7D&ViewCount=0&IsXslView=TRUE&IsCSR=TRUE&ListViewPageUrl=[SITE_URL]%2FForms%2FAllItems1.aspx&InplaceSearchQuery=MySearchTerm
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What was the previous patch level and current patch level? Have you looked at ULS logs for the query result returns or the SharePoint Query Search Tool (https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool)?

Comment: @Trevor Seward: I updated the question

Comment: You left out the previous version and a useful ULS/result from the query tool.

Comment: I was not implied in the server update and don't know the previous version and though the SearchQueryTool looks like a nice debugging tool, I'm not sure how to use it for the inplview query. As I mentioned this query uses the same result source as the global search box which does return the correct results (after appending the wildcard symbol).